# Add column to existing MapType column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with several columns. One of these is a map (MapType).
The keys inside this map-column differ from row to row. This means something like this is possible:

```
+----------+-----------------+
|     col_1|            col_2|
+----------+-----------------+
|         7| key_1 -> value_1|
|         5| key_2 -> value_2|
|         4| key_3 -> value_3|
+----------+-----------------+
```

What i want to do is add the first column to this map-column to get something like:

```
+----------+-----------------------------+
|     col_1|                        col_2|
+----------+-----------------------------+
|         7| key_1 -> value_1, col_1 -> 7|
|         5| key_2 -> value_2, col_1 -> 5|
|         4| key_3 -> value_3, col_1 -> 4|
+----------+-----------------------------+
```

But i cant figure out how to add the first column to the map while perserving the individual keys inside the map-column.

Comment: what is your version of spark ?

Comment: My version is 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version **2.4.0**, you have access to a lot of new functions to manipulate map types.

Assuming `df` is your dataframe :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "col_2",
    F.map_concat(
        F.col("col_2"),
        F.map_from_entries(F.array(F.struct(F.col("col_1"))))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a try. Totally lost th overview, of which functions there are.